# Flutter: How to update widget that was created outside of build using setState

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I update testOffset in snakeCell, if snakeCell is created outside of build? This is a simplified version of my problem, in reality snakeCell is a list of widgets, I must create new widgets and update them in runtime, not in build method.
Code:

```
Offset testOffset = Offset.zero;
late AnimatedSlide snakeCell;

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /* // When I create snakeCell there, setState in initState works
    snakeCell = AnimatedSlide(
      offset: testOffset, //snakeOffsets[offset]
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      child: FlutterLogo(size: 50),
    );
    */

    return Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: CustomPaint(
            size: Size(500, 500),
            painter: GamePainter(),
          ),
        ),
        snakeCell
      ]
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // If I create snakeCell there, setState doesn't work 
    snakeCell = AnimatedSlide(
      offset: testOffset, //snakeOffsets[offset]
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      child: FlutterLogo(size: 50),
    );

    setState(() {
      testOffset -= Offset(2, 0);
    });
  }
}
```

I tried to search information about this problem in the internet and tried to use code that is above.

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of observable data that is shared between two separate widgets.  That's called "State Management", solved by packages like Riverpod.